# What are some web-API-frameworks for .NET? Like Frapi or grape

Tags: c#, .net, api, frameworks

There are two interesting frameworks for use in Ruby and PHP that provide tools for building APIs.

Ruby: Grape
https://github.com/intridea/grape/wiki

Php: Frapi
http://getfrapi.com/

Does anyone know of an equivalent undertaking in .NET?

For instance, in Grape, you can create a ruby class as follows:

```
class MyAPI < Grape::API
    prefix 'api'

    get 'hello' do
        {:hello => 'world'}
    end
end
```

Which allows you to make an HTTP Request like this:

```
GET /api/hello
{“hello”:”world”}
```

That's pretty sweet.

---

**EDIT**

---

Upon reflection it seems as though a WCF Http Rest service might be the most similar to Frappi and Grape, which makes my question kind of silly. But I'm still hoping to collect able some projects that have tools or even some frameworks that are specific to creating APIs.

Sprache, (answered below) seems very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kayak is a lightweight server. It let's you easily create those routes and responses:

https://github.com/kayak/kayak

From the examples:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Kayak;

namespace KayakExamples
{
    class Simple
    {
        public static void Run()
        {
            var server = new DotNetServer();

            var pipe = server.Start();

            server.Host((env, respond, error) =>
                {
                    respond(new Tuple<string, IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>, IEnumerable<object>>(
                            "200 OK",
                            new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>() 
                            {
                                { "Content-Type",  new string[] { "text/html" } }
                            },
                            new object[] { Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello world.") }
                        ));
                });

            Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + server.ListenEndPoint);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();

            pipe.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good article on *external domain-specific languages*:
http://nblumhardt.com/2010/01/building-an-external-dsl-in-c/

Here's the tool discussed in the article, *Sprache*:
http://code.google.com/p/sprache/

Comment: This is an interesting project, but isn't it a little more specific to parsing? This is a good start, but I am also looking for something that abstracts out the creation of REST services.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly you want to do. You could expose your API via a [JSON or XML HTTP web service using WCF](http://www.gtrifonov.com/blog/2009/02/05/Building_JSON,XML_REST_API_using_WCF_services.aspx). You could also expose a controller/action Rails-like API via [ASP.Net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc).

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe I'm a little off base with this question. ASP.Net wouldn't quite be a solution congruent to Grape, but I suppose REST WCF is...

Comment: ASP.Net may not but the ASP.Net MVC might be. You would be able to create a controller with certain actions and your view can simply be your XML/JSON output.

Comment: Right, but if you take a look at the example above, there is no need to create a controller or a view. It's a simple extension of a class and a method definition with some special hooks. The example gets much deeper in fact, where the entire API can be defined very rapidly. ASP.MVC is much like Zend Framework or Ruby on Rails, but Grape and Frapi are different in the sense that they provide a very concise framework for building REST APIs. I have little experience with WCF-REST, but I think this might be all that is needed.